# Get run time of parallel Prolog program

Tags: multithreading, prolog, swi-prolog, execution-time

I'm using SWI Prolog and have a program that goes like this:

```
main :-
   statistics(runtime, [T0|_]),
   thread_create(...),
   thread_create(...),
   thread_join(...),
   thread_join(...),
   statistics(runtime, [T1|_]),
   T is T1 - T0,
   print(T).
```

The problem is that for some reason `T` is always 0. However, if the `thread_create / thread_join` part is replaced with its equivalent serial code, I get a non-zero time.

A 'workaround' (but I think it's not 100% corret) I've found is using `walltime` instead of `runtime` as the first parameter to `statistics/2`, but I read that the wall time is like the actual time I could measured on, say, a real wall clock and should not be used to measure program execution time.

EDIT: Also, if I add a similar timing mechanism in each thread's goal, the timings are also non-zero. I assume that `runtime` only measures CPU time for the thread running it and evaluates to `0` in the first thread (the one running `main`) because that thread does very few other than delegate the real work to the newly created threads.

Comment: Sadly, using system_time in the same way as in the original post not only gives a T of 0 in main, but also in each thread's goal (runtime worked if placed in each tread's function).

Comment: Well, I think your analysis at the end is correct, so just measure in each thread.

Comment: That's a bit harder to do (I'll have to add those timings), but also, I thought that getting those statistics per thread will increase the threads' runtimes. However, I noticed that the walltime measurement is actually VERY accurate.. the timing I measure using walltime in `main` is almost the same as the maximum between each of the threads' runtimes.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the *compatibility keys*, mostly originating from Quintus Prolog when there were no threads and milliseconds were considered very accurate.  Use the native keys.  One is `process_cputime`, returning the CPU time of the entire process (all threads).  There is also `thread_cputime`
returning the CPU time of all *finished* threads and just `cputime` returning the time of the calling thread.  All values are floats expressing time in seconds.  Resolution depends on the OS, typically quite accurate on modern OSes.

Comment: I actually tried the first two, but I would like to get the runtime of the entire program (which, I think, should be a value close to a maximum of the runtimes of the threads).  Is the only way of obtaining this to do something like `statistics(cputime,T0),..statistics(cputime, T1), T is T1 
-T0` in each thread, return this `T` and compute the maximum of all `T`s after joining all threads?

Comment: `process_cputime` does this.  This includes the cputime of finished threads though.  This all may depend on the hosting OS as there is quite a large number of different ways to implement this that all work on some subset of OSes.